# Each element list in python is a SQL query. How to check elements to see if they are executable

Tags: python, mysql, list

Lets say I have a list where each element has sql queries :
For example say,

```
CREATE TABLE STATION 
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
CITY CHAR(20), 
STATE CHAR(2), 
LAT_N REAL, 
LONG_W REAL);
```

is the first element in my list and has one query, and maybe for second I have 2 queries and it looks something like,

```
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES (13, 'Phoenix', 'AZ', 33, 112); 
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES (44, 'Denver', 'CO', 40, 105);
```

Is there an API or tool in python I should look into that would allow these queries to be tested to see if they are executable(check to make sure syntax is correct)?

Thanks!